# How to Derive the Matrix Inverse Formula Without Using Gauss-Jordan

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, gaussian-elimination

I understand how to use Gaussian elimination to find the inverse of a square matrix, though I’m not a fan of tedious calculations by hand, especially considering the cubic time complexity of the method. So I would like to know if there are any simple and concise derivations of general inverse formulae for square matrices that do not use this algorithm. Firstly, is there a nice alternative derivation for the following closed form $2 \times 2$ matrix formula?

$$
A^{-1} = \pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}^{-1}={1\over\det A}\pmatrix{d&-b\cr-c&a\cr}
$$

Can such a derivation technique generalize to $n \times n$ matrices of arbitrary dimension?

Comment: You might find [this wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Analytic_solution) to be helpful. Unfortunately, there is no nice generalization to the $2 \times 2$ inversion formula. The closest thing is the cofactor expansion formula, which is significantly more tedious to calculate than Gaussian elimination for matrices $3\times 3$ or larger.

Comment: I suppose the Cayley-Hamilton decomposition is also arguably a generalization of the $2\times 2$ formula, but that also quickly gets complicated.

Comment: I'm not certain whether by "derivation" you mean an algorithm to compute it, or a proof to see that it's true. If by chance the latter, yes there are definitely other ways to prove a generalization of that result to $n\times n$ matrices other than Gaussian elimination.